# Count different non-zero values of two 2D arrays in Python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to find out how many values in 2D array `array1` are different from values in `array2` on same positions (x, y) and not equal `0` in `array2` using Numpy.

```py
array1 = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 0]])
array2 = numpy.array([[1, 2], [0, 3]])
print(numpy.count_nonzero(array1 != array2)) # 2
```

Example above prints `2`, because 0 and 3 are different. Is there any way not to count difference if value in `array2` is `0`? Something like that (which is not working - `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more then one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`):

```
print(numpy.count_nonzero(array1 != array2 and array2 != 0)) # Should be 1.
```

Comment: It seems you want OR instead of AND: "array1 are different from values in array2" OR "not equal 0 in array2". am I correct?

Comment: `np.logical_and(array1 != array2, array2 != 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 0]])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [0, 3]])
```

---

Filter out `b`'s zero values

`np.nonzero` returns indices, this uses [multidimensional index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) to filter out the zero values.

```
In [144]: b.nonzero()
Out[144]: (array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 1], dtype=int64))

In [145]: a[b.nonzero()]
Out[145]: array([1, 2, 0])

In [146]: b[b.nonzero()]
Out[146]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [147]: c = a[b.nonzero()] != b[b.nonzero()]

In [148]: c.sum()
Out[148]: 1
```

---

This uses [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to filter out the zero values.

```
In [149]: b != 0
Out[149]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [150]: a[b != 0]
Out[150]: array([1, 2, 0])

In [151]: b[b != 0]
Out[151]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [152]: c = a[b != 0] != b[b != 0]

In [153]: c.sum()
Out[153]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by replacing `and` with multiplication:

```
print(numpy.count_nonzero((array1 != array2) * (array2 != 0)))
```